Windows Version (Problem detected with Windows installation) ! Get-Process failed to complete
I have this problem on Flutter, when running flutter doctor -v , I cant seem to find the solution, Help would be apprecciated!
I've been trying all kinds of stuff , like reinstalling flutter , updating Windows, I've even checked Windows Version in all kinds of different places and I've ran Get Process from Powershell and it runs fine with no problems except it only fails with flutter doctor., I've tried changing to flutter channel master and back to stable ,sfc/scannow,  DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth it still doesnt clear the error.
PS C:\Users\felix\StudioProjects\bandera_musical> flutter doctor -v           
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    10.0.22631.3880], locale es-MX)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at C:\Users\felix\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (6 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[!] Windows Version (Problem detected with Windows installation)
    ! Get-Process failed to complete

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.4)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33530.505
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)    

[√] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code      
    • Flutter extension version 3.48.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows        
      [Version 10.0.22631.3880]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      126.0.6478.127
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge
      126.0.2592.102

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

